# PlayN Fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, playn

I don't know why it is not working.
I want to start my game in fullscreen on desktop (Java).

**Code**

```
@Override
public void setToFullScreen() {
    int screenHeight = graphics().screenHeight();
    int screenWidth = graphics().screenWidth();
    
    log().debug("ScreenHeight: " + screenHeight);
    log().debug("ScreenWidth: " + screenWidth);

    graphics().setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
}
```

**The log says:**

> ScreenHeight: 480
>
> ScreenWidth: 640

My possible resolution would be full hd - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayN is not made for Java-fullscreen-mode.

The Java-Applet view is made for debugging reasons for all other platforms.

If you want to use fullscreen mode, you probably need to change the PlayN-java-sourcecode.
You maybe have to use the method
java.awt.GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(...)

Answer (score 1):

The commands

```
graphics().screenWidth();
graphics().screehHeight();
```

give you the size of the playn game window.

if you want to adjust the screen size to Full HD, you have to do it like this:

```
graphics().setSize(1920, 1080);
```

this will set the size of the playn window to 1920, 1080. Howerver, this does not set your game to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which version you are using, but in the bleeding edge (1.5-SNAPSHOT) those functions return the REAL screen resolution every time.

Comment: how could not? just download the bleeding edge and compile your game with it

Comment: It is only helpful for a specific moment in time and further you gave no example proving that this is correct.  It is more of a comment than anything.